# Why Does The Reflection Principle Fail For Infinitely Many Sentences?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I've read the proof that ZF cannot be finitely axiomatized via the reflection principle and the 2nd incompleteness theorem. Since ZF can be countably axiomatized, the finiteness requirement in the reflection principle must be necessary; if the reflection principle worked for infinitely many formulas, the same argument would show that ZF couldn't be countably axiomatized either, as far as I can tell. But I can't figure out why the reflection principle fails for infinitely many formulas.

The reflection principle states that for a finite set of formulas $\{\phi_i\}$ and a starting set $M_0$, we can extend $M_0$ to $M$ so that for each formula $\phi_i$ we have $\phi_i^M (x_1,...,x_n) \iff \phi_i(x_1,...,x_n)$. In *Jech*, this is proved essentially as follows (thm 12.14): we first take the set of all subformulas of our starting set of formulas $\{\phi_i\}$, which is again finite. Let's say these subformulas are $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots\sigma_k\}$ Then we repeatedly "adjoin" elements to our starting set $M_0$ to get a set $M$ so that the following holds for all $u,\dots \in M$:

$$∃x \ \sigma_j (u, . . . , x) → (∃x ∈ M)\ \sigma_j (u, . . . , x),\ j = 1, ..., k \hspace{1cm} (*)$$

To do this, we begin by letting the $u,\dots$ range over $M_0$, and adjoin an appropriate $x$ value for each formula and each $\sigma_j$ to give $M_1\supseteq M_0$. We can just iterate this procedure a countably infinite number of times to get $M_{i+1}\supseteq M_i$ for each $i$, and let $M$ be the union of the $M_i$. At the end, (*) clearly holds for every $\sigma_j$, because each choice of $u\dots$ will only use variables from some finite iterate $M_i$, and then the desired $x$ for the righthand side lives in $M_{i+1}$. It's easy to conclude from this that $\phi_i^M (x_1,...,x_n) \iff \phi_i(x_1,...,x_n)$, just by building up from the atomic formulas one layer at a time.

I can't find a problem with using this same argument for an infinite set of formulas. We can again just take the set of subformulas, and establish (*) by iteratively constructing $M_{i+1}$ from $M_i$. This should still work because each individual subformula only has finitely many variables. I can't see anything else remotely troublesome for extending the argument. As explained at the start, there must be a problem with this argument, but finding it is eluding me.

Many thanks!

Comment: These are very *very* ***very*** delicate issues. Not seeing them immediately is not a big deal. It takes time until you're used to the difference between theory, meta-theory and all that stuff.

Comment: At the end of the day, the issue is that you need to formalize satisfiability. (Jech 's book addresses this.)

Comment: I get why my answer was downvoted, I've been here for five years and gained enough haters, sure. But I really don't get why the question was downvoted. Anyone has the slightest idea?

Comment: @Asaf: Nope; it looks to me like an obvious candidate for **up**voting. (And I did – the answer as well.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the formulas and the reflecting models live in completely separate worlds.

The formulas are part of the meta-theory, and the model is part of the universe of the theory. More specifically, while we can internalize finitely many formulas at once (where finite here means in the meta-theory sense), we cannot internalize infinitely many formulas at the same time.

More specifically, since the enumeration of the formulas lives "outside" the world, there is no guarantee that there is a supremum to the sequence of models $M_i$, since the sequence itself might not exist inside the universe.

Comment: Verbal critique works better. And if I understand wrong, I'd be *very* happy to learn better.

Comment: Cool, thanks! 

Am I understanding correctly in saying there will be some infinite sets of axioms that could be internalized together, but we can't guarantee that a given infinite set can be internalized? The incompleteness theorem argument seems to show that the ZF axioms in particular cannot be internalized simultaneously in ZF.

Comment: Well. Sure, but pretty vacuously. Just add parameters and don't use them in a specific instance of Replacement, for example.

Comment: It's an interesting question and answer.  Let me push a bit on the answer: the failure of reflection definitely implies that an sequence of models of increasing sets of formulas may not have a supremum.  But why is it that the latter explains the former?  You suggest that it's because the enumeration of the formulas is "outside" the model.  But in what sense of "outside"?  Seen as syntactic objects they might as well live in a (standard) model's omega.

Comment: @mmw: Suppose that $\kappa$ is inaccessible. $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC and it includes *all* the reals. Since it is a set model, we can define in $V$ the truth predicate for $V_\kappa$. But that is just a real number and a choice of encoding, both of which live *inside* $V_\kappa$. Now tell me, how does that not contradict Tarski's theorem about undefinability of the truth? :-)

Comment: Nice:-) that helps to clarify what i had in mind.  In the case of the question, a (coded) axiomatization of $ZF$ is definable, so it seems like an enumeration of the axioms must in some sense exist in the model.

Comment: @mmw: To clarify my point from the previous comment, just because something is in the model, it doesn't mean that the models knows that it is that something.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's what's bugging me is: what is it about the coded axiomatization of ZF which the model fails to know?  E.g., a standard model might be taken to "know" about syntax, and about the consequence relation.

Comment: @mmw: It is simply unaware that the meta theory, or meta universe uses the same coding, or the same truth predicate, or that it is the model's own truth predicate. It's "just another real" as far as the model is concerned.